# Converting Prometheus rate queries to Datadog

Tags: prometheus, datadog

We are switching from the Prometheus stack to Datadog.

I am trying to convert the rate promq to datadog query.

Prometheus query:

```
sum(rate(keycloak_request_duration_bucket{method="GET", le="100.0"}[30m]))
```

I have tried to write query in Datadog, it looks something like:

```
sum:xcr_keycloak.keycloak_request_duration.bucket{method:get,upper_bound:100.0}.as_rate()
```

Is this right? How would this query look like in Datadog?

Comment: It is advisable to show your attempt and explain how it failed you.